# Error message while trying to upload image

Tags: php

So my image gets uploaded without issues but what is this error I get after image gets uploaded on form submit?

[image: Here is the error]

This is the bit of my php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
    {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));   //line 16
        $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"blogUploads\images/".$image_name);   //line 17     
        $image_name=time().".".$ext;        
        watermark_image($tmp_name,"blogUploads\images/".$image_name);
        $img = ''.$image_name.'';
    }else{
        $img = '';
    }

}
```

Comment: `$_FILES['file']['name']!=''` is not the correct way to check for checking `file` instead you can use `$_FILES['file']['error'] != 4''` also for using `end` you  need to get the `exploded` result within variable and then need to use `end($your_exploded_variable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for error :"filename strict standards only variables should be passed by reference" in end(explode())

1st Assign the result of explode Array into a variable and then pass that variable to end like:

```
$tmp = explode('.', $namefile);
$file_extension = end($tmp);
```

or

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
$extension = $path_parts['extension'];
$fileName = $path_parts['filename'];
```

2nd for move_uploaded_file() error just ensure that destination path(2nd parameter) is valid (plus ensure that your upload folder has write permissions )

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
```

follow "Complete Upload File PHP Script" from
 http://w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

PS:also assignment of $image_name variable should  before move_uploaded_file()

Comment: still not getting it mate could you show me on my cose? would really appreciate it

Comment: @sms247 one error disappeared now the move_uploaded_file() is reamining

Comment: follow "Complete Upload File PHP Script" from
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 1):

Correct your directory structure on line 17 by this :

```
$fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"blogUploads\images\".$image_name);;   //line 17
```

and here also

```
watermark_image($tmp_name,"blogUploads\images\".$image_name);
```

Comment: can you explain what you face because it is the correct syntax for directory.

Comment: now the only error i face is in this like $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"blogUploads/images/".$image_name);

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpC185.tmp' to 'blogUploads/images/' in C:\wamp\www\jobs\post-article.php on line 18

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\wamp\www\jobs\post-article.php on line 18

Comment: provide your complete directory structure for upload image like this : 
$fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"C:\wamp\www\jobs\blogUploads\images\".$image_name);;   //line 17

Comment: you can also provide correct relative path according to structure for resolve uploading issue.